# LocalDateTime not displaying as timestamps (ie as a long) java 8 spring boot 2.2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, timestamp, localdatetime

After visiting all pages about it where I found and tried many many ideas, none worked for me so I write this post.
My API in java 8 spring boot 2.2.0 have beans that are generated from xsd files. I recently changes the Date type to LocalDateTime (because deprecation so it's time to change).
The problem is, before, Date were display in a timestamp format (as a long) and now LocalDateTime are display in an array and I don't want it.

What I tried to solve:

- I had a WebMvc annotation on a confiuration class, removed it, not solved the issue.
- I added WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: true in my application.yml (tried many formats on this properties)
- I have a configuration class for message converters where I tried to manually force timestamps.
- I wanted to add a Json annotation in my beans but as it generate from xsd, I don't know if it is possible. it is ?

Here is a snippet of the configuration class for message converters :

```
@Configuration
   public class MVCConfigure implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.removeIf(c -> c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);

        jacksonObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        converters.add(httpMessageConverterV1V2);
```

Nothing of theses solutions worked and I still get an array for my LocalDateTime (and I want a long).

Here is how I get the LocalDateTime :

```
private LocalDateTime getFirstLocalDateTime(final SolrDocument doc, final String key) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = null;
        Date solrDate = (Date) doc.getFirstValue(key);
        if(solrDate != null){
            ldt = solrDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        }
        return ldt;
    }
```

ps : The reason I use Date to get the Date from SolrDoc is because I can't cast to LocalDateTime directly

actual value :
"lastIndexedDate": [
2022,
1,
4,
2,
2,
2,
655000000
]

desire value :
"lastIndexedDate": 1641261722655

So, it is possible to get what I want ?

Comment: I forgot to say, I tried also to add jackson-datatype-jsr310 dependency

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is only a date plus a time of day, it does not represent a moment in time because it has no time zone or offset from UTC. It cannot be converted to epoch millis without attaching a zone or an offset. I would try an `Instant`, an `OffsetDateTime` or a `ZonedDateTime` in your case. By the way, please show code that is more relevant to your problem and add some example values (input, desired, actual).

Comment: @deHaar Thanks for your fast answer, I edited my post and I think understand I should modify something when I get value for the variable ldt but I don't see how.

Comment: I think you just need an `Instant`, would be sufficient if you just want the epoch millis. Ok, it depends on the code that produces your output `"lastIndexDate": …`, can you show that, too?

Comment: @deHaar yes please see the getFirstLocalDateTime method, this is from which I get the output

Comment: The actual value you posted is an array of the single parts of a `LocalDateTime` (`[ 2022, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 655000000 ]` means `[year, month of year, day of month, hour of day, minute of hour, second of minute, fractions of second]`) which cannot be converted to epoch milliseconds without further adjustment. Your desired output is a moment in time (an `Instant`) as `long`, which leads to the conclusion that `LocalDateTime` is not the data type your method should return. Can you change it to return `Instant` and adjust dependencies accordingly?

Comment: You could start with `private Instant getFirstSomething(…) …` and `return ((Date) doc.getFirstValue(key)).toInstant();`. Maybe find out if you can skip the intermediate casting to `Date` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @deHaar who gave me some hints I've found how to proceed.

I created a custom serializer :

```
public class LocalDateTimeSerialize extends StdSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    public LocalDateTimeSerialize(Class<LocalDateTime> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        Long l = localDateTime.toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset())
                .toEpochMilli();
        jsonGenerator.writeString(l.toString());
    }
}
```

I change my extendMessageConverters to use this custom serializer in my objectMapper :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()
                .addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerialize(LocalDateTime.class)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather set this config so you don't have to create a custom serializer:

```
spring:
    jackson:
        serialization:
          write-dates-as-timestamps: true
```

That or set it in your mapper:

```
   @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    }
```

Comment: I tried both, I've mentioned it in the tried list.